# Adding rows to a non-singular square matrix will keep or increase its minimum singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

I have a question to this post:
[Show adding rows to a non-singular square matrix will keep or increase its minimum singular value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446797/show-adding-rows-to-a-non-singular-square-matrix-will-keep-or-increase-its-minim/3552634#3552634)

There Tony asked how to show that the minimum singular value increases or stays the same when adding a row to a non-singular matrix. 
I'm also interested in how to show this. I understand the answer of loup blanc until he says that the last step is so obvious.

How do you know that 
$x^T(A^*_1A_1+A^*_2A_2)x\geq x^TA^*_1A_1x$ implies that the $spectrum(A^*_1A_1)\leq spectrum(A^*A)$?
As far as I know, you can have a look at the inequality while using an eigenvector of matrix $A_1$ for example. But that doesn't mean that that same vector is also an eigenvector for $A$. So how do you know which one of the singular values is then smaller?

I also tried to describe the eigenvector of the smallest singular value of $A_1$ through a linear combination of the ones eigenvectors of $A$, but that didn't get me anywhere either.

I'd be grateful for any help because I think it shouldn't be that hard to show that this implication hold, but I just can't seem to see how to at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of LB's answer: first of all, his $x^T$ should really be an $x^*$ in this context.  Let $\lambda_{\text{min}}(M)$ denote the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix $M$ (LB calls this "min spectrum" instead).  Rayleigh's theorem says that if $M$ is Hermitian, we have
$$
\lambda_{\min} (M) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} x^*Mx.
$$
With that, we can say that
$$
\lambda_{\min}(A_1^*A_1) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} x^*(A_1^*A_1)x \leq \min_{\|x\| = 1} x^*(A_1^*A_1 + A_2^*A_2)x = \lambda_{\min}(A_1^*A_1 + A_2^*A_2).
$$

---

Here's an explanation that I find much more intuitive:
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{\min} \pmatrix{A_1\\A_2} 
&= \min_{\|x\| = 1} \left\| \pmatrix{A_1\\A_2}x\right\|
= \min_{\|x\| = 1} \left\| \pmatrix{A_1 x\\A_2 x}\right\|
\\&\geq \min_{\|x\| = 1} \left\| \pmatrix{A_1 x\\0}\right\|
= \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|A_1x\| = \sigma_\min (A_1).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: sometimes adding an extra step as a bridge can be helpful  
$\min_{\|x_1\| = 1} x_1^*(A_1^*A_1)x_1 \leq \min_{\|x_1\| = 1} x_1^*(A_1^*A_1)x_1 + \min_{\|x_2\| = 1} x_2^*(A_2^*A_2)x_2 \leq \min_{\|x_3\| = 1} x_3^*(A_1^*A_1 + A_2^*A_2)x_3$  

because both are positive semidefinite matrices, and 2 choices are better than one

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Omnomnomnom, but I still don't get all of it.
I looked up Rayleigh's quotient and found that you can say the following:
$\lambda_{min}(M)=v_{\lambda_{min}}^*M v_{\lambda_{min}}$.
I don't see that you can just exchange $v_{\lambda_{min}}$ through $\underset{||x||=1}{min}x^*Mx$.

I have the same problem with your more intuitive version. How do you know that the first step is valid?

Comment: Some answers explaining how maximizing/minimizing the Rayleigh quotient gives you a maximal/minimal eigenvalue are [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723629/81360).  Both this characterization of the minimal eigenvalue and the characterization I give of the smallest singular values are standard results; if you'd like a reference, see for instance Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*.